# Test class works in sandbox, fails in production validation

Tags: soql, unit-test, test-setup

I'm at a loss. I don't understand why my test class works fine in the sandbox (100% coverage), yet when I run a deployment validation in production, I get the following error for each test method:

> *System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Stack Trace:
>   Class.contentDocumentLinkTriggerTest.internalResolutionNote: line 53,
>   column 1*

(This is the first SOQL query in each test method attempting to return the relevant ContentNote inserted in Test Setup.)

```
@IsTest
public class contentDocumentLinkTriggerTest {

@TestSetup static void setupData() {

    Case internalCase = new Case(Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerInternalCase',
                                 Description = 'test description',
                                 RecordTypeId = [Select Id
                                                 From RecordType
                                                 Where DeveloperName = 'Internal_Case'
                                                 Limit 1].Id,
                                 Type = 'Bug',
                                 Status = 'Backlog',
                                 Origin = 'Admin',
                                 Priority = 'P3 - Minor',
                                 HasResolutionNotes__c = False);

    Case customerCase = new Case(Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerCustomerCase',
                                 Description = 'test description',
                                 RecordTypeId = [Select Id
                                                 From RecordType
                                                 Where DeveloperName = 'Customer'
                                                 Limit 1].Id,
                                 Type = 'Bug',
                                 Status = 'Open',
                                 Origin = 'Email',
                                 Priority = 'Medium',
                                 HasResolutionNotes__c = False);

    ContentNote cnResolution = new ContentNote(Title = 'Resolution Notes TriggerTest',
                                               OwnerId = [Select Id
                                                          From User
                                                          Where IsActive = True
                                                          And CompanyName Like '%[our company name]%'
                                                          Limit 1].Id);

    ContentNote cnNoResolution = new ContentNote(Title = 'Some Different Notes TriggerTest',
                                                 OwnerId = [Select Id
                                                            From User
                                                            Where IsActive = True
                                                            And CompanyName Like '%[our company name]%'
                                                            Limit 1].Id);

    insert internalCase;
    insert customerCase;
    insert cnResolution;
    insert cnNoResolution;

}

@IsTest
static void internalResolutionNote() {

    ContentNote cnResolution = [Select Id
                                From ContentNote
                                Where Title = 'Resolution Notes TriggerTest'
                                Limit 1];

    Case internalCase = [Select Id
                         From Case
                         Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerInternalCase'
                         Limit 1];

    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(ContentDocumentId = cnResolution.Id,
                                                      LinkedEntityId = internalCase.Id,
                                                      ShareType = 'I');

    Test.startTest();

        insert cdl;

    Test.stopTest();

    Case checkCase = [Select Id, HasResolutionNotes__c
                      From Case
                      Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerInternalCase'];

    System.assert(checkCase.HasResolutionNotes__c);

}

@IsTest
static void customerResolutionNote() {

    ContentNote cnResolution = [Select Id
                                From ContentNote
                                Where Title = 'Resolution Notes TriggerTest'
                                Limit 1];

    Case customerCase = [Select Id
                         From Case
                         Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerCustomerCase'
                         Limit 1];

    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(ContentDocumentId = cnResolution.Id,
                                                      LinkedEntityId = customerCase.Id,
                                                      ShareType = 'I');

    Test.startTest();

        insert cdl;

    Test.stopTest();

    Case checkCase = [Select Id, HasResolutionNotes__c
                      From Case
                      Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerCustomerCase'];

    System.assert(!checkCase.HasResolutionNotes__c);

}

@IsTest
static void internalNoResolutionNote() {

    ContentNote cnNoResolution = [Select Id
                                  From ContentNote
                                  Where Title = 'Some Different Notes TriggerTest'
                                  Limit 1];

    Case internalCase = [Select Id
                         From Case
                         Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerInternalCase'
                         Limit 1];

    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(ContentDocumentId = cnNoResolution.Id,
                                                      LinkedEntityId = internalCase.Id,
                                                      ShareType = 'I');

    Test.startTest();

        insert cdl;

    Test.stopTest();

    Case checkCase = [Select Id, HasResolutionNotes__c
                      From Case
                      Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerInternalCase'];

    System.assert(!checkCase.HasResolutionNotes__c);

}

@IsTest
static void customerNoResolutionNote() {

    ContentNote cnNoResolution = [Select Id
                                  From ContentNote
                                  Where Title = 'Some Different Notes TriggerTest'
                                  Limit 1];

    Case customerCase = [Select Id
                         From Case
                         Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerCustomerCase'
                         Limit 1];

    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(ContentDocumentId = cnNoResolution.Id,
                                                      LinkedEntityId = customerCase.Id,
                                                      ShareType = 'I');

    Test.startTest();

        insert cdl;

    Test.stopTest();

    Case checkCase = [Select Id, HasResolutionNotes__c
                      From Case
                      Where Subject = 'TestContentDocumentTriggerCustomerCase'];

    System.assert(!checkCase.HasResolutionNotes__c);

}
}
```

Comment: That error always suggests sharing rules to me. No personal experience with ContentNote but as you are doing something explicit with the owner FYI https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E2a6QAC.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link - I had no idea that was the case! (I'm addressing the substance of your comment as a reply below since it's very similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting up your ContentNote test data, you are selecting from User to set OwnerId. Make sure to insert test users before selecting from them.

Comment: That was the underlying issue. I didn't feel like inserting a user and for my purposes, it shouldn't matter who the Note owner is in theory in order to trigger the class... But I didn't realize the sharing implications. After reading through this, I realized there's no need to explicitly assign an owner, so I just removed that from the note setup and it all worked fine. Thanks!